# Best practice for DynamoDB composite primary key travelling inside the system (partition key and sort key)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sorting, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am working on a system where I am storing data in DynamoDB and it has to be sorted chronologically. For `partition_key` I have an `id` (uuid) and for `sort_key` I have a `date_created` value. Now originally it was enough to save unique entries using only the ID, but then a problem arose that this data was not being sorted as I wanted, so a sort_key was added.

Using python boto3 library, it would be enough for me to get, update or delete items using only the id primary key since I know that it is always unique:

```
import boto3

resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = resource.Table('my_table_name')

table.get_item(
    Key={'item_id': 'unique_item_id'}
)
table.update_item(
    Key={'item_id': 'unique_item_id'}
)
table.delete_item(
    Key={'item_id': 'unique_item_id'}
)
```

However, DynamoDB requires a sort key to be provided as well, since primary keys are composed partition key and sort key.

```
table.get_item(
    Key={
        'item_id': 'unique_item_id',
        'date_created': 12345          # timestamp
    }
)
```

First of all, is it the right approach to use sort key to sort data chronologically or are there better approaches?

Secondly, what would be the best approach for transmitting partition key and sort key across the system? For example I have an API endpoint which accepts the ID, by this ID the backend performs a `get_item` query and returns the corresponding data. Now since I also need the sort key, I was thinking about using a hashing algorithm internally, where I would hash a JSON like this:

```
{
    "item_id": "unique_item_id",
    "date_created": 12345
}
```

and a single value then becomes my identifier for this database entry. I would then dehash this value before performing any database queries. Is this the approach common?

Comment: Good question, @Robertas.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, is it the right approach to use sort key to sort data chronologically

Sort keys are *the* means of sorting data in DynamoDB.  Using a timestamp as a sort key field is the right thing to do, and a common pattern in DDB.

> DynamoDB requires a sort key to be provided ... since primary keys are composed partition key and sort key.

This is true.  However, when reading from DDB it is possible to specify *only* the partition key using the [query operation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query) (as opposed to the`get_item` operation which requires the full primary key).  This is a powerful construct that lets you specify which items you want to read from a given partition.

You may want to look into KSUIDs for your unique identifiers.  KSUIDs are like UUIDs, but they contain a time component.  This allows them to be sorted by generation time.  There are several KSUID libraries in python, so you don't need to implement the algorithm yourself.

Comment: Good answer @Seth. However, I have some performance degradation concerns. Do you have any thoughts on how much worse the performance will get when using the query operation instead of get item operation to retrieve (in any case) a single row?

Comment: @Seth I should have probably added that `get_item` is not a problem, because `query` solves it. It still would not solve the issue regarding updating and deleting. Now doing a `query` before `update_item` would be two database calls instead of one, just seems like a step in the wrong direction. Did not know about KSUIDs, thanks!

Comment: @RobertasStankevičius I don't know anything about your data, but I don't see any other way to pinpoint a specific primary key item if your sort key is a created_at timestamp.  If you used a KSUID and it was in your PK and SK (e.g. PK#[ksuid], SK#[ksuid]) you wouldn't need two trips to DDB to issue an update/delete.  All you'd need is the ksuid to identify the item.  

In general, I wouldn't worry about multiple roundtrips to DDB.  Sure, it may not be optimal, but DDB is pretty dang fast.  With single-digit millisecond performance, you may be just fine.

Comment: @LaimonasSutkus According to the DDB docs, `get_item` is the most efficient way to fetch a single item.  Anecdotally, I've heard that the `query` operation offers equivalent performance when querying a single item, but I have no hard evidence for that.